# Access computer over VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, synology

This is my setup:

I have a Synology NAS that is running a OpenVPN server. On the same network I have a laptop (#1 IP: 192.168.1.11) that I would like to access.

I connect to the VPN server with a laptop (#2) that is connected to internet over a local/WiFi network (network #1). I can connect to VPN server fine. Once connected, I can reach the NAS on IP 10.8.0.1 and get IP 10.8.0.10 on laptop #2.

The OpenVPN network has an IP range of 10.8.0.0 - 10.8.0.255 but only allows for 5 simultaneous connections.

My question is what IP should I use to connect to laptop #1 from laptop #2 when I'm connected to the VPN server?

I have tried with IP 192.168.1.11 but it doesn't work. I think it is actually trying to connect to IP 192.168.1.11 on the local/WiFi network #1. If I use my phone as a hotspot (network #2) then I can connect to laptop #1 using IP 192.168.1.11.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `DHCP` IP range on network #1 from `192.168.1.50 - 192.168.1.255` to `192.168.2.50 - 192.168.2.255`. Now I can connect to `192.168.1.11`, laptop #1